# Pass by Value or by Reference and Impure or pure functions

Tags: programming-languages

Beginner question: I am teaching myself the two passing techniques: Pass by Value and Pass by Reference.

Can Pass by Value change the states of an object? If yes, how? Which of the two techniques changes the states of an object? 
Also, are Impure Functions based on Pass by Ref. and Pure Functions on Pass by Value?

I'd be glad if someone clears my concept.

Comment: @Evil, I would not rollback your edit for now (or forever). I do think it is fine to include a bias to Java. If I were in my earlier years, I would like to ask the same question requesting examples in the language of my choice, although pseudocode or other language should not be bad, too.

Comment: @Evil of course, an answer (whose author is supposed to be much more experienced not only in Java but also in other languages) should try to make the examples in Java look like pseudocode as much as possible or write examples that look like Java code. An answer could emphasize that the general principles are not restricted to Java only.

Comment: @Apass.Jack no, I do not expect to forbid Java in answer. Programming languages questions are ok, I think more about OP expectations, with Java and potential anwers in pseudocode. It is a good question and I understand picking Java and sticking to it, simply answers here may miss expectations. Your idea to pseudocode similar to Java may not be helpful enough. If OP requests Java code, I think SO may be better place. If you prefer rollback for reasons you gave, it is fine with me.

Comment: @Evil, I will let OP to weigh in. One of my messages is to welcome newcomers, trying to making them feel comfortable, without lowering the quality of this site. After all, we have been beginners once, from time to time and forever.

Comment: Well, nevermind...

Comment: @user9836598 be careful that the example given in Evil's answer uses c/c++ syntax, which is very different from Java when it deals with references.

Answer (score 3):

Pass by value and pass by reference are about function calls (method calls in case of OOP).

Pass by value means that variable is copied in function and any changes to variable are visible only within scope, where it was changed, if you pass reference then any modification to variable in the function is preserved after function call.

```
int x = 5;
void PassByValue(y) {
   y = 6;
  // some code
}
void PassByReference(&y) {
  y = 6;
  // some code here
}
PassByValue(x);
// here x is still 5
PassByReference(ix);
// here x is equal 6
```

Let O be object `{x: 8}`, that it's private variable x and setter method O.set(y) with code this.x = y;
If you pass by value or pass by reference, it doesn't matter, the state of object is changed.

Impure function has side effects outside of it's scope, so:

```
void Impure() {
  x = 6;  
}
```

It does not get any parameters, but changes variable in outer scope, this is side effect.

Another property of impure function is that they do not solely rely on input parameters, one canonical example is:

```
int rand(int x) {
  return rand() * x;
}
```

Pure function returns the same result at every call, so for example math functions obey this property.
Any observable side effect: I/O operation, mutation, outer scope modification, network trafic, and so on, are impure.

Answer (score 2):

Just saying: There are more than two parameter passing methods.

There is the FORTRAN method: Variables are passed by reference, values are evaluated and stored away in an anonymous variable which is passed by reference. To have a bit of fun, literals are permanently stored in an anonymous variable, and if the called function changes the parameter, a literal is changed forever. Fun days :-)

There is the Algol “call by name” method: The actual expression is passed. If you pass a[i] as a parameter x, and assign x = 1, it assigns to a[i]. If you change i, it assigns to the newly evaluated a[i].

Swift has two interesting methods. In-out passes a variable by value, then assigns back to the variable when the method returns (differently from reference). And auto-closure parameters pass an expression, which is evaluated when needed and only when needed. Similar to Algol, except you cannot assign to such a parameter.